# Can I remove a specific $post from $posts if I know the ID of the $post?

Tags: php, laravel

If my query returns `$posts` which contain 3 posts with ids of 1,2 and 3, can I somehow remove the `$post` with id of 2 so that when I loop through `$posts` I only output the posts with id of 1 and 3?

Comment: be more specific, do you want to remove the post in the controller or in the view, are you using blade?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using blade:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   @if(!$post->id == 2 )
     {{$post->title}}
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: That did work, originally I was thinking about doing this in the controller but this works fine as well.

Comment: Please don't put such logic into the frontend - that's some stuff that should be handled by the backend

Answer (score 2):

after fetching to $posts, you can filter

```
$posts = $posts->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->id != 2;
});
```

see this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter

Comment: This will give you only posts with `$id == 2` in the result. You should use `$collection->reject($callback)` instead.